# jQuery bind keyup, keydown - Can't type into form fields

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

After a lot of debugging I found the reason why I cannot type any text into my form fields.

I have a jQuery function to catch some keys that I use in my JS app.

```
$(document).bind 'keyup keydown', (e) -> 
    shifted = e.shiftKey
    cntrled = e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).bind('keyup keydown', function(e) {
      shifted = e.shiftKey;
      return cntrled = e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey;
    });
```

Why can I not type into form fields with that in place?

As soon as I remove that part I can type again.

Comment: Show your full code of keyup/keydown function. But suppose the only reason there would be `e.preventDefault()` or `return false;` in code of that callback.

Comment: That is the full code, and yes it is coffeescript

Comment: It would help to see the generated JavaScript.

Comment: I Added the generated Js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the value cntrled which cancels the event.

In Coffeescript the last value in your function will be returned.

Return true as the last line in the handler.

JavaScript equivalent of what you are doing now...

```
$(document).bind('keyup keydown', function (e) {
    var shifted = e.shiftKey
        , cntrled = e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey;
    return cntrled;
});
```

Change it into...

```
$(document).bind('keyup keydown', function (e) {
    var shifted = e.shiftKey
        , cntrled = e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey;
    return true;
});
```